# Working with Mongo in .Net Core web api

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core

I have a working Mongo and .Net Core app, but still need to access the mongo DB through C#.  I am just testing this by trying to make the connection in the program.cs file.  At the top I have:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Core;
using MongoDB.Bson;
```

When I run:

```
var mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var db = mongo.GetDatabase("cvpz");   
mongo.getCollection("people");
```

I get this error:

```
Program.cs(16,19): error CS1061: 'MongoClient' does not contain a definition for 'getCollection' and no extension method 'getCollection' accepting a first argument of type 'MongoClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/src/src/Identity.api/Identity.api.csproj]
```

Now, I can access the DB through the commandline through 'mongo localhost/cvpz'.  Btw, I am using Ubuntu to run .Net Core.

When I run createCollection() I get a similar error.  How do I use C# to interact with Mongo?

One last thing, I should have all the necessary packages, I have these in my .csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core" Version="2.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.3.0" />
```

Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 4):

Two things. 'GetCollection' should have an uppercase G. It also requires a generic parameter indicating the document type being stored. For you example:

```
var mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var db = mongo.GetDatabase("cvpz");   
var coll = mongo.GetCollection<People>("people");
```

Reference: [IMongoDatabase.GetCollection](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoDatabase_GetCollection__1.htm)

Comment: Do I need to add it to the .csproj file?  Or jusr do 'using IMongoDatabase.GetCollection'?  Also, do I need to get a using statement for every command I want to use?

Comment: @Joel Add what to the csproj file? From this question and one you asked 15 hours ago, you have the correct references as is. "Reference: IMongoDatabase.GetCollection" is a link to documentation.

Comment: haha sorry, been staring at a computer screen to long.  Thanks man for the help! :)